# CSV file getting multiple records

Tags: php, csv

I am exporting result of a query in a csv file. The code is as shown below:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE(punchdetails.punchin) as punchday,punchdetails.punchin,punchdetails.punchout,employeedetails.employeename
                            FROM punchdetails join(employeedetails) ON punchdetails.employeeid=employeedetails.employeeid 
                            AND punchdetails.employeeid=$employeeid AND DATE(punchdetails.punchin)=$fromdate";

header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$private=1;
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$select_c = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_c))
{
    $intime = strtotime($row['punchin']);
    $mysqlintime = date( 'H:i:a', $intime );
    $outtime = strtotime($row['punchout']);
    $mysqlouttime = date( 'H:i:a', $outtime );
    $result.=$row['employeename'].','.$row['punchday'].','.$mysqlintime.','.$mysqlouttime;
    $result.="\n";
    echo $result;
}
```

When I execute the query it is returning records correctly. But when I download the result of the query as csv file, the records are getting duplicated. I am getting the resultant csv file data as shown below:

```
Sonu,2013-09-26,10:55:am,11:12:am

Sonu,2013-09-26,10:55:am,11:12:am

Kristo,2013-09-26,11:23:am,11:24:am
```

I am not getting what is the problem. Can anybody help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get duplicates of every record, or just some? Also, when you run the query you say it returns the correct records - how have you tested this?

Comment: I echoed the resultant query and executed in phpmyadmin. Currently I have only 2 records satisfying the query. Only the first record is getting duplicated now.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem

you concatinate the `result` with each row, then echo. So, each time you echo - you will echo all the previous results + the current result.

Either, change:

```
$result.=$row['employeename'].','.$row['punchday'].','.$mysqlintime.','.$mysqlouttime;
$result.="\n";
```

to:

```
echo $row['employeename'].','.$row['punchday'].','.$mysqlintime.','.$mysqlouttime;
echo "\n";
```

or move the `echo $result;` outside the while loop

Comment: yes it worked when I moved     echo $result; outside the while loop. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo $result outside of the while loop:

```
$result='';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_c))
{
    $intime = strtotime($row['punchin']);
    $mysqlintime = date( 'H:i:a', $intime );
    $outtime = strtotime($row['punchout']);
    $mysqlouttime = date( 'H:i:a', $outtime );
    $result.=$row['employeename'].','.$row['punchday'].','.$mysqlintime.','.$mysqlouttime;
    $result.="\n";
}     
echo $result;
```